# Assignment in python class argument

Tags: python, function, class, oop, arguments

I don't have much experience with python and probably this is duplicated question.. sorry for that
Let assume I have the following code:

```
class myclassI:
    def __init__(self, key=None, data=None):
        self.key = key
        self.data= data

class myclassII:
    def addInfo(self, key, data)
        NewInfo = myclassI(key=key, data=data)
```

I see this type of call and I was wondering what do we mean by performing "key=key" when we are calling "myclassI"?
Many thanks for any suggestions!

Comment: It's just assigning `key` which is passed to `myclassII` constructor to `key` of `myclassI` constructor.

Comment: Can you elaborate on your answer? Why not just having "NewInfo = myclassI(key, data)" is this a "best practice" to follow or any other reason

Comment: You can call it in either way - `myclassI(key, data)` and `myclassI(key = key, data = data)` both will work in this case.

Comment: The second way is used, when you want to pass arguments in random order, for example, `myclassI(data = data, key = key)` should also work I guess.

Comment: @mahdi You absolutely can. However, it's a good practice when there are many arguments, as giving the name adds clarity. In addition, many 3rd-party libraries are keyword-argument-only, so you need to specify the name.